# How to flatten the nested Array?

Tags: javascript

How do I flatten the nested Array in the Array?

Here is the example input Array,

```
const input = [
{
   id: 1,
   name: 'Charles',
   otherFields: [{
       id: 2,
       name: 'Pung',
   }, {
       id: 3,
       name: 'James',
   }]
}, {
   id: 4,
   name: 'Charles',
   otherFields: [{
       id: 5,
       name: 'Pung',
   }, {
       id: 6,
       name: 'James',
   }]
}

]
```

Output Array I want to get.

```
[{
   id: 1,
   name: 'Charles'
}, {
   id: 2,
   name: 'Pung',
}, {
   id: 3,
   name: 'James',
}, {
   id: 4,
   name: 'Charles'
}, {
   id: 5,
   name: 'Pung',
}, {
   id: 6,
   name: 'James',
}]
```

I want to somehow get the output in one statement like

```
input.map((sth) => ({...sth??, sth.field...})); // I'm not sure :(
```

Comment: how deep is the nesting?

Comment: one degree deep as shown in the example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) you can take out the `otherFields` property, and returning an array containing the parent item and the other array:

```js
const input = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Charles',
  otherFields: [{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Pung',
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'James',
  }]
}];
console.log(
  input.flatMap(({ otherFields, ...item }) => [item, ...otherFields])
);
```

Comment: super great answer. Thanks a lot. What if I want to map the `name` into > `custom_name`?

Comment: For that to be readable, I think you'd want to separate it out onto a separate line. Map the array afterwards: `.flatMap(...).map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, custom_name: name }))` You can do it in a single `.flatMap` too, but I think it'd look a bit worse

Comment: thanks a lot! idk why people downvoted my question though

Comment: great answer :D

Comment: I'm getting this TS Error: 'MyType | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Comment: Does the `otherFields` always exist on an item in the input array? What is the `MyType`?

Comment: I'm getting api response. otherFields is Array<MyType>

Comment: I should've included it in the description my bad

Comment: api response which is stored in redux. I'm getting the data from the redux store

Comment: I accepted your response first since it's answering my question. ..!!!!

Comment: Here is another problem...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560415/how-to-flatten-out-the-array-and-assign-new-keys-ts-js

Answer (score 1):

For more than one level, you could take a recursive approach of flattening.

```js
const
    flat = ({ otherFields = [], ...o }) => [o, ...otherFields.flatMap(flat)],
    input = [{ id: 1, name: 'Charles', otherFields: [{ id: 2, name: 'Pung' }, { id: 3, name: 'James', otherFields: [{ id: 4, name: 'Jane' }] }] }],
    result = input.flatMap(flat);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm getting this TS Error: 'MyType | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560415/how-to-flatten-out-the-array-and-assign-new-keys-ts-js