# how to flatten out the array and assign new keys? (TS, JS)

Tags: javascript, typescript

From this long JSON file, I want to pick few keys and values.

```
[{
  c_id: "1",
  c: "google",
  displayName: "display name",
  myResults: [{ //type: Array<MyResult>
     type: 'TEXT',
     name: 'my text',
     label: 'my RealText',
     id: '2',
     description: 'sdf'
     }, {
     type: 'STRING',
     name: 'my text',
     label: 'my sdf',
     id: '3',
     description: 'sdf',
     }
  ],
  fieldValues: 'Object',
  id: "d-ss-dd-asda-sdcv",
  index: 0,
  name: "google",
  type: "NAH",
}, 
{
  c_id: "sddc-ss",
  connector: "facebook",
  displayName: "d f d",
  myFields: [],
  myResults: [{ //type: Array<MyResult>
     type: 'TEXT',
     name: 'my text',
     label: 'my RealText',
     id: '5',
     description: 'sdf'
     }, {
     type: 'STRING',
     name: 'my text',
     label: 'my sdf',
     id: '6',
     description: 'sdf',
     }
  ],
  fieldValues: 'Object',
  id: "s-sdf-sdfdc",
  index: 1,
  name: "action",
  type: "ACTION"
}];
```

Output

```
[{
   id: "d-ss-dd-asda-sdcv", //c_id
   label: 'google' //c
   index: 0
}, {
   id: '2',
   label: 'my RealText',
}, {
   id: '3',
   label: 'my sdf',
}, {
   id: "sddc-ss", //c_id
   label: 'facebook' //c
   index: 0
}, {
   id: '5',
   label: 'my RealText',
}, {
   id: '6',
   label: 'my sdf',
}]
```

How do I make this work using flatList?

```
input.flatMap(({ myResults, ...item }) => [item, ...myResults])
```

Comment: Your data is weird. c_id for google is '1', not "d-ss-dd-asda-sdcv"

Answer (score 1):

```
const result = data.flatMap(({ c_id, c, index, myResults }) => ([
    { id: c_id, label: c, index }, 
    ...myResults.map(({ id, label }) => ({ id, label }))
  ]))
```

Maybe this would work, but I'm just guessing because your data seems inconsistent. c_id and id seem to get switched, `google` is the "c" key but `facebook` is the "connector key"

Comment: I'm getting `myResults can be possilby undefined` error :(

Comment: `{id, labe},,,, must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.` <- This error followed up